# TypeError while intermixing Prototypal and Constructor pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand prototypal pattern and constructor pattern in JavaScript. I read that they are equivalent. So, I thought of intermixing them and got stumped by the results:

Defining the constructor:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.describe = function(){ return "Name: "+this.name };
};
```

Testing the constructor:

```
munish = new Person('Munish');  // Person { name="Munish",  describe=function()}
munish.constructor;  // Person(name)
munish.constructor.name;  // "Person"
Person.prototype;  // Person {}
Object.getPrototypeOf(munish) === Person.prototype;  // true
```

Now, trying to use dunder proto and C.prototype to create new objects

```
nitin = {
  name: 'Nitin',
  __proto__: Person.prototype, 
  // __proto__: Object.getPrototypeOf(munish),  // same as above
}
nitin.describe();  // TypeError: nitin.describe is not a function
```

Taking another approach by using Object.create() to create new objects

```
nitin = Object.create(Person.prototype);
nitin.name = 'Nitin';
nitin.describe();  // TypeError: nitin.describe is not a function
```

Or, if I try

```
nitin = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Person('Nitin')));
nitin.describe();  // TypeError: nitin.describe is not a function
```

Why the code is throwing TypeError? I spent almost a full day trying to figure out where I went wrong. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nitin` object doesn't have a `describe` property because it's not on the prototype. It's a property you're adding to the *instance* when the constructor is called. If you never call the constructor, it's never added. Just referring to `Person.prototype` doesn't call `Person`.

You could put `describe` on `Person.prototype`:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.describe = function(){ return "Name: "+this.name; };
```

And then

```
var nitin = Object.create(Person.prototype);
nitin.name = "Nitin";
nitin.describe();
```

But of course, you have to duplicate the logic from the constructor every time you do that. If you're going to have a constructor function, it's best to actually use it. If you have a reason for constructing the object without using `new`, you can still use the constructor to initialize it. (Despite their names, constructors don't actually construct anything, they *initialize* things. `new` is what does the actual construction — or, of course, `Object.create`.) Here's how:

```
var nitin = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Person.call(nitin, "Nitin");
nitin.describe();
```

Of course, that's just a really long-winded way to write:

```
var nitin = new Person("Nitin");
nitin.describe();
```

Comment: That means, at the first step when I defined the constructor, its prototype was just an empty object. In the second step when I created an object using constructor, the "new" (without quotes) executed the constructor and added properties "name" and "describe" to the newly created object. 
But, executing Person.prototype.describe = function(){ return "Name: "+this.name; }; adds "describe" to prototype and so it was available in your nitin object. Thanks for such a nice explanation :-)